# Create multiple indexes on multiple properties in Neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I have to create indices for around 15 different labels and 400 different properties. Currently I have a bash script that look like:

```
echo "CYPHER CREATE INDEX ON :Person(uuid);" | $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-shell
sleep 5
echo "CYPHER CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name);" | $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-shell
sleep 5
echo "CYPHER CREATE INDEX ON :Person(surname);" | $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-shell
sleep 5
echo "CYPHER CREATE INDEX ON :Animal(uuid);" | $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-shell
sleep 5
echo "CYPHER CREATE INDEX ON :Animal(name);" | $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-shell
sleep 5
```

The problem is that after a while I see this warning:

```
2016-08-31 13:18:16.448+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.i.c.MonitorGc] GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for 432ms.
```

which eventually leads to a out of memory exception:

```
2016-08-31 11:28:54.579+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexPopulationJob] Failed to populate index: [:GeneticVariant(mapped_gene) [provider: {key=lucene, version=1.0}
]] Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.AbstractLockService.acquireNodeLock(AbstractLockService.java:52)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.locking.ReentrantLockService.acquireNodeLock(ReentrantLockService.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.NeoStoreIndexStoreView$NodeStoreScan.run(NeoStoreIndexStoreView.java:212)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator$BatchingStoreScan.run(BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator.java:384)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexPopulationJob.indexAllNodes(IndexPopulationJob.java:138)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexPopulationJob.run(IndexPopulationJob.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:104)
2016-08-31 11:30:52.653+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexPopulationJob] Forcefully shutting down executor.
BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator{activeTasks=0, executor=java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@354e43e[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 21], batchedUpdates = [org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.BatchingMultipleIndexPopulator$BatchingIndexPopulation@32c99a02 - 4589 updates], queuedUpdates = 0}
```

I tried to solve that by adding `sleep` after each command, but it's not enough. Is there a smarter way to make this work?

I am using Neo4j server 3.0.0 on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the indices and unique constraints that you want in your DB, you can use the [APOC plugin](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) procedure `apoc.schema.assert` to ensure that they all exist. Any index/constraint that does not already exist will be created, and **NOTE: any existing ones not specified in your call will be dropped**.

For example, if you wanted to assert that these (and only these) indices exist:

```
:Person(name)
:Person(surname)
:Animal(name)
```

and these (and only these) unique constraints exist:

```
:Person(uuid)
:Animal(uuid)
```

you can make this Cypher query:

```
CALL apoc.schema.assert(
  {Person:['name', 'surname'], Animal:['name']},
  {Person:['uuid'], Animal:['uuid']})
YIELD label, key, unique, action
RETURN *;
```

If the DB had no indices or constraints before, the result would look like this:

```
╒═══════╤═══════╤══════╤══════╕
│action │key    │label │unique│
╞═══════╪═══════╪══════╪══════╡
│CREATED│name   │Animal│false │
├───────┼───────┼──────┼──────┤
│CREATED│name   │Person│false │
├───────┼───────┼──────┼──────┤
│CREATED│surname│Person│false │
├───────┼───────┼──────┼──────┤
│CREATED│uuid   │Animal│true  │
├───────┼───────┼──────┼──────┤
│CREATED│uuid   │Person│true  │
└───────┴───────┴──────┴──────┘
```